# AngularJS, доступ к глубоко закопанным элементам скопа

Tags: angularjs

В документации не нашел, в гугле тоже(возможно не смог грамотно на английском сформулировать вопрос)

Есть контроллер с глубоким скопом. Типа такого

```
{
    user:{
        sm:{
            general:{
                app:[], 
                rights:[], 
                phone:'',
                options:{
                    ....
                        }
                    }
           }
         }
}
```

Хочется заполнить темплейт начиная с **user.sm.general.options** и очень не хочется везде этот длиннющий префикс вставлять.

Мечтается что-то вроде (ng-use - это с потолка)

```
<ng-use="user.sm.general.options as opt">
    логин: {{opt.login}}
    пароль:  {{opt.pass}}
    роль:  {{opt.role}}
</ng-use>
```

Comment: `ng-init` делает практически то что надо, но проще сохранить нужный объект в переменную внутри самого контроллера и использовать ее

Comment: Как сказал @Grundy, есть два варианта. В темплейте написать `<difv ng-init="opt = user.sm.general.options">
    логин: {{opt.login}}
    пароль:  {{opt.pass}}
    роль:  {{opt.role}}
</ng-use>`. Или в контроллере `$scope.opt=user.sm.general.options`. Кстати, есть вариант написать директиву `ng-use`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko оформите ответом пожалуйста и я его сразу приму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказал @Grundy, есть два варианта.

В темплейте написать

```
<div ng-init="opt = user.sm.general.options"> 
  логин: {{opt.login}} 
  пароль: {{opt.pass}} 
  роль: {{opt.role}} 
</div>
```

Или в контроллере `$scope.opt=user.sm.general.options`.

Кстати, есть вариант написать директиву `my-use`.

```js
angular.module("ExampleApp", [])
  .controller("ExampleController", function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      sm: {
        general: {
          app: [],
          rights: [],
          phone: '',
          options: {
            login: "53453",
            pass: "sfsdf",
            role: "adm"
          }
        }
      }
    };
    $scope.optController = $scope.user.sm.general.options;
  })
  .directive("myUse", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: { in : "=",
        out: "@"
      },
      replace: false,
      transclude: true,
      template: "<span ng-transclude></span>",
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.$$childHead[scope.out] = scope.in;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <h2>Использование директивы. Свойство <code>opt</code> создается в дочернем $scope(id={{$id}}).</h2> 
  opt = {{opt|json}}
  <my-use in="user.sm.general.options" out="opt">
    <div>логин:{{opt.login}}</div>
    <div>пароль: {{opt.pass}}</div>
    <div>роль: {{opt.role}}</div>
    <div>$scope(id={{$id}})</div>
  </my-use>

  <h2>Использование <code>ng-init</code>. Свойство <code>optInit</code> создается в общем $scope(id={{$id}})</h2> 
  optInit = {{optInit|json}}
  <div ng-init="optInit = user.sm.general.options">
    <div>логин:{{optInit.login}}</div>
    <div>пароль: {{optInit.pass}}</div>
    <div>роль: {{optInit.role}}</div>
    <div>$scope(id={{$id}})</div>
  </div>

  <h2>Использование инициализации в контроллере. Свойство <code>optController</code> создается в общем $scope(id={{$id}})</h2> 
  optController = {{optController|json}}
  <div>
    <div>логин:{{optController.login}}</div>
    <div>пароль: {{optController.pass}}</div>
    <div>роль: {{optController.role}}</div>
    <div>$scope(id={{$id}})</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/rvnysafm/).

Comment: а зачем в родительский скоп добавлять? почему не оставить в изолированном?

Comment: а почему не просто: `scope[scope.out] = scope.in;`?

Comment: Может, я что-то не так делаю. Но `scope[scope.out] = scope.in`  не работает. Думаю, потому что `transclude` создает еще один дочерний изолированный `scope`.

Comment: это потому, что тут transclude не нужен

Comment: Как в таком случае сохранить `html`, при использовании директивы? Не могли бы вы модифицировать мой jsfiddle, без использования `transclude `.